# How many possible ways we can update case status and comments from third party API to salesforce

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforce-id

Third party API is sending the case status, ID and case comments to salesforce. Apart from batch class, Is there any way to update the records in salesforce?

Comment: I would not expect to use a Batch Apex class in your use case. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Third party API is sending status, comments and Multiple record ID in JSON format to update in salesforce. Which is the best possible way to update the Multiple records in salesforce?

Comment: I am new to salesforce. I thought of batch Apex class. Anyother solution is there?

Comment: Depends how many is in multiple. Another approach could be to create an ApexRest service to parse JSON and update necessary information

Comment: Multiple records like 100 records per day. Can you give an example with code?

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce has several APIs to submit multiple records at once, listed in the [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite.htm) documentation. The Composite request, for example, can update a record, and insert/update related child records all at once. While you *can* write code to parse data, it's much easier for everyone if you can just use the standard APIs.